# Mutation/Lollipop plot using Trackviewer package, using the EBI Proteins REST API

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am looking to plot different variants in a gene on R/RStudio. I am ultimately looking to plot different mutations/variants inside the gene, and do it on both sides to compare new findings.

I was using the g3viz package, but since I needed to use different colours to better map functional domain, I switched to the TrackViewer package.

I am using this particular example and modelling my code on the example of pulling the EMBL-EBI API on here, but I keep hitting this error about the organism ID not being found and I am unsure of how to rectify this.

When I skipped those two lines of code and ran it again.

```
library(httr) # load library to get data from REST API
APIurl <- "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/" # base URL of the API
taxid <- "9606" # human tax ID
gene <- "TP53" # target gene
orgDB <- "org.Hs.eg.db" # org database to get the uniprot accession id
eid <- mget("TP53", get(sub(".db", "SYMBOL2EG", orgDB)))[[1]]

**Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'envir' in selecting a method** for function 'mget': object 'org.Hs.egSYMBOL2EG' not found
```

Full code segment from below link

```
library(httr) # load library to get data from REST API
APIurl <- "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/" # base URL of the API
taxid <- "9606" # human tax ID
gene <- "TP53" # target gene
orgDB <- "org.Hs.eg.db" # org database to get the uniprot accession id
eid <- mget("TP53", get(sub(".db", "SYMBOL2EG", orgDB)))[[1]]
chr <- mget(eid, get(sub(".db", "CHR", orgDB)))[[1]]
accession <- unlist(lapply(eid, function(.ele){
  mget(.ele, get(sub(".db", "UNIPROT", orgDB)))
}))
stopifnot(length(accession)<=20) # max number of accession is 20

tryCatch({ ## in case the internet connection does not work
  featureURL <- paste0(APIurl, 
                       "features?offset=0&size=-1&reviewed=true",
                       "&types=DNA_BIND%2CMOTIF%2CDOMAIN",
                       "&taxid=", taxid,
                       "&accession=", paste(accession, collapse = "%2C")
  )
  response <- GET(featureURL)
  if(!http_error(response)){
    content <- content(response)
    content <- content[[1]]
    acc <- content$accession
    sequence <- content$sequence
    gr <- GRanges(chr, IRanges(1, nchar(sequence)))
    domains <- do.call(rbind, content$features)
    domains <- GRanges(chr, IRanges(as.numeric(domains[, "begin"]),
                                     as.numeric(domains[, "end"]),
                                     names = domains[, "description"]))
    names(domains)[1] <- "DNA_BIND" ## this is hard coding.
    domains$fill <- 1+seq_along(domains)
    domains$height <- 0.04
    ## GET variations. This part can be replaced by user-defined data.
    variationURL <- paste0(APIurl,
                           "variation?offset=0&size=-1",
                           "&sourcetype=uniprot&dbtype=dbSNP",
                           "&taxid=", taxid,
                           "&accession=", acc)
    response <- GET(variationURL)
    if(!http_error(response)){
      content <- content(response)
      content <- content[[1]]
      keep <- sapply(content$features, function(.ele) length(.ele$evidences)>2 && # filter the data by at least 2 evidences
                       !grepl("Unclassified", .ele$clinicalSignificances)) # filter the data by classified clinical significances.
      nkeep <- c("wildType", "alternativeSequence", "begin", "end",
                 "somaticStatus", "consequenceType", "score")
      content$features <- lapply(content$features[keep], function(.ele){
        .ele$score <- length(.ele$evidences)
        unlist(.ele[nkeep]) 
      })
      variation <- do.call(rbind, content$features)
      variation <- 
        GRanges(chr, 
                IRanges(as.numeric(variation[, "begin"]),
                        width = 1,
                        names = paste0(variation[, "wildType"],
                                       variation[, "begin"],
                                       variation[, "alternativeSequence"])),
                score = as.numeric(variation[, "score"]),
                color = as.numeric(factor(variation[, "consequenceType"]))+1)
      variation$label.parameter.gp <- gpar(cex=.5)
      lolliplot(variation, domains, ranges = gr, ylab = "# evidences", yaxis = FALSE)
    }else{
      message("Can not get variations. http error")
    }
  }else{
    message("Can not get features. http error")
  }
},error=function(e){
  message(e)
},warning=function(w){
  message(w)
},interrupt=function(i){
  message(i)
})
**ERROR: unable to find an inherited method for function 'content' for signature '"response"'**
```

LINK TO THE PACKAGE: https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/trackViewer/inst/doc/lollipopPlot.html

Comment: From the limited amount of information you provided, this doesn't appear to be a plotting issue but a retrieval of information from the web.  Can you provide additional details, the code snippet above is incomplete.

Comment: These lines: `mget(eid, get(sub(".db", "CHR", orgDB)))` are not making sense.  It looks like you are trying to access some loaded database/variable but the above code does load anything, so there is nothing to get.  Where did the above code come from?  I suggest going here and manually trying to generate a request: "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/doc/#!/proteins/search" then you have something to debug up above.

Comment: So the mget is pulling the specific genes on the particular chromosome. The above code came from this vignette published by the package authors on this link - https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/trackViewer/inst/doc/lollipopPlot.html

Comment: Ok, reading the above link closer, I think there are a few additional libraries you need to load for the code above to work.  For example there is a "org.Hs.eg.db" library reference in the next section from the above.  At the very bottom of link is showing all of the libraries the authors had loaded.  You many to play around see which ones you have loaded versus the reference.  I have no knowledge of Bioconductor nor do I want to learn.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this worked for me and produces an mutation plot that I can work with!

```
library(httr) # load library to get data from REST API
    library(org.Hs.eg.db)
    library(trackViewer)
    APIurl <-"https://www.ebi.ac.uk/proteins/api/" # base URL of the API
    taxid <- "9606" # human tax ID
    gene <- "PCDH19" # target gene
    orgDB <- "org.Hs.eg.db" # 
org database to get the uniprot accession id
eid <- mget("PCDH19", get(sub(".db", "SYMBOL2EG", orgDB)))[[1]]
chr <- mget(eid, get(sub(".db", "CHR", orgDB)))[[1]]
accession <- unlist(lapply(eid, function(.ele){
  mget(.ele, get(sub(".db", "UNIPROT", orgDB)))
  
}))
stopifnot(length(accession)<=20) # max number of accession is 20

tryCatch({ ## in case the internet connection does not work
  
  featureURL <- paste0(APIurl,
                       
                       "features?offset=0&size=-1&reviewed=true",
                       
                       "&types=DNA_BIND%2CMOTIF%2CDOMAIN",
                       
                       "&taxid=", taxid,
                       
                       "&accession=", paste(accession, collapse = "%2C")
                       
  )
  response <- GET(featureURL)
  
  if(!http_error(response)){
    
    content <- httr::content(response)
    
    content <- content[[1]]
    
    acc <- content$accession
    
    sequence <- content$sequence
    
    gr <- GRanges(chr, IRanges(1, nchar(sequence)))
    
    domains <- do.call(rbind, content$features)
    
    domains <- GRanges(chr, IRanges(as.numeric(domains[, "begin"]),
                                    
                                    as.numeric(domains[, "end"]),
                                    
                                    names = domains[, "description"]))
    
    names(domains)[1] <- "" ## this is hard coding.
    
    domains$fill <- 1+seq_along(domains)
    
    domains$height <- 0.04
    
    ## GET variations. This part can be replaced by user-defined data.
    
    variationURL <- paste0(APIurl,
                           
                           "variation?offset=0&size=-1",
                           
                           "&sourcetype=uniprot&dbtype=dbSNP",
                           
                           "&taxid=", taxid,
                           
                           "&accession=", acc)
    
    response <- GET(variationURL)
    
    if(!http_error(response)){
      
      content <- httr::content(response)
      
      content <- content[[1]]
      
      keep <- sapply(content$features, function(.ele) length(.ele$evidences)>2 && # filter the data by at least 2 evidences
                       
                       !grepl("Unclassified", .ele$clinicalSignificances)) # filter the data by classified clinical significances.
      
      nkeep <- c("wildType", "alternativeSequence", "begin", "end",
                 
                 "somaticStatus", "consequenceType", "score")
      
      content$features <- lapply(content$features[keep], function(.ele){
        
        .ele$score <- length(.ele$evidences)
        
        unlist(.ele[nkeep])
        
      })
      
      variation <- do.call(rbind, content$features)
      
      variation <-
        
        GRanges(chr,
                
                IRanges(as.numeric(variation[, "begin"]),
                        
                        width = 1,
                        
                        names = paste0(variation[, "wildType"],
                                       
                                       variation[, "begin"],
                                       
                                       variation[, "alternativeSequence"])),
                
                score = as.numeric(variation[, "score"]),
                
                color = as.numeric(factor(variation[, "consequenceType"]))+1)
      
      variation$label.parameter.gp <- gpar(cex=.5)
      
      lolliplot(variation, domains, ranges = gr, ylab = "# evidences", yaxis = FALSE)
      
    }else{
      
      message("Can not get variations. http error")
      
    }
    
  }else{
    
    message("Can not get features. http error")
    
  }
  
},error=function(e){
  
  message(e)
  
},warning=function(w){
  
  message(w)
  
},interrupt=function(i){
  
  message(i)
  
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).